# H2 set schema changes schema_search_path

Tags: h2

If I have a schema_search_path set and I wish to create a bunch of tables using a common script by setting the schema and not explicating the
schema in the table create (common script could be used in multiple schemas, this also sets the schema_search_path to just the specified schema.

This seems like an undesirable side affect.

Answer (score 0):

Value set by `SET SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH` is not affected by any other commands.

But this value is only used when an identified is not qualified with the schema and an object with this name doesn't exist in the current schema (affected by `SET SCHEMA` command).

For example, tables referenced by non-qualified names are searched in the following order:

1. Tables of the current schema.
2. Local temporary tables. (Currently they also include query aliases from the `WITH` clauses, but this may be changed when somebody will implement a separate scope of identifiers for these views.)
3. Tables of each schema from `SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH`, if any. When multiple schemas are specified, they order has a meaning, they are processed in the same order.
4. Legacy or compatibility tables, such as `DUAL` or `SYSDUMMY1` in DB2 and Derby compatibility modes.

The first table matched by its name will be used.

This is a complex case, for the most types of database objects only steps (1) and (3) are performed.

If you think that something is not going as described here and you can create a standalone test case (Java / JDBC / SQL only, no third-party libraries), you can create a bug report on GitHub:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues